# Multidimensional Array Calculate based on rows and columns

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I having trouble with multidimensional array. I want to get the Results based on calculate from rows and columns

I have array probabilitas like this

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 0.21739130434783
        [1] => 0.043478260869565
        [2] => 0.23809523809524
        [3] => 0.071428571428571
        [4] => 0.058823529411765
        [5] => 0.20833333333333
    )

    [1] => Array (
        [0] => 0.08695652173913 
        [1] => 0.17391304347826
        [2] => 0.095238095238095
        [3] => 0.17857142857143 
        [4] => 0.23529411764706
        [5] => 0.16666666666667
    )

    [2] => Array (
        [0] => 0.043478260869565
        [1] => 0.17391304347826
        [2] => 0.095238095238095
        [3] => 0.17857142857143
        [4] => 0.11764705882353
        [5] => 0.16666666666667
    )

    [3] => Array (
        [0] => 0.08695652173913
        [1] => 0.17391304347826
        [2] => 0.19047619047619
        [3] => 0.17857142857143
        [4] => 0.23529411764706
        [5] => 0.083333333333333
    )

    [4] => Array (
        [0] => 0.21739130434783
        [1] => 0.17391304347826
        [2] => 0.19047619047619
        [3] => 0.035714285714286
        [4] => 0.11764705882353
        [5] => 0.16666666666667
    )

    [5] => Array (
        [0] => 0.17391304347826
        [1] => 0.17391304347826
        [2] => 0.095238095238095
        [3] => 0.17857142857143
        [4] => 0.11764705882353
        [5] => 0.16666666666667
    )

    [6] => Array (
        [0] => 0.17391304347826
        [1] => 0.08695652173913
        [2] => 0.095238095238095
        [3] => 0.17857142857143
        [4] => 0.11764705882353
        [5] => 0.041666666666667
    ) 
)
```

if run on browser wil be like this
[image]

and i want to get the final results like this

```
countCol1 = 0,94197665
countCol2 = 0,960859982
countCol3 = 0,960555517
countCol4 = 0,948500044
countCol5 = 0,953102906
countCol6 = 0,956259856
```

but i got error like this

> Message: log() expects parameter 1 to be float, array given

what's wrong with my code ? can someone help me?

this my code

```
$kriteria = [C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6];
$alternatif = [ALT1,ALT2,ALT,ALT4,ALT5,ALT6,ALT7];
$nEntropy = array();
for ($i=0;$i<count($kriteria);$i++)
    {
        for ($j=0;$j<count($alternatif);$j++)
            {
                $nEntropy[$j][$i] = 
                    ((-1/log(7)) * 
                    ($probabilitas[$j][$i]*log($probabilitas[$i])) +
                    ($probabilitas[$j][$i]*log($probabilitas[$i])) + 
                    ($probabilitas[$j][$i]*log($probabilitas[$i])) + 
                    ($probabilitas[$j][$i]*log($probabilitas[$i])) + 
                    ($probabilitas[$j][$i]*log($probabilitas[$i])) + 
                    ($probabilitas[$j][$i]*log($probabilitas[$i])) + 
                    ($probabilitas[$j][$i]*log($probabilitas[$i])));
            }
    }
```

to calculate it I use this formula.

> countCol1 = (-1/log(7)) *
>   ((0,217391304*log(0,217391304))+(0,086956522*log(0,086956522))+(0,043478261*log(0,043478261))+(0,086956522*log(0,086956522))+(0,217391304*log(0,217391304))+(0,173913043*log(0,173913043))+(0,173913043*log(0,173913043)))
>
> countCol2 = (-1/log(7)) *
>   ((0,043478261*log(0,043478261))+(0,173913043*log(0,173913043))+(0,173913043*log(0,173913043))+(0,173913043*log(0,173913043))+(0,173913043*log(0,173913043))+(0,173913043*log(0,173913043))+(0,086956522*log(0,086956522)))
>
> countCol3 = (-1/log(7)) *
>   ((0,238095238*log(0,238095238))+(0,095238095*log(0,095238095))+(0,095238095*log(0,095238095))+(0,19047619*log(0,19047619))+(0,19047619*log(0,19047619))+(0,095238095*log(0,095238095))+(0,095238095*log(0,095238095)))
>
> countCol4 = (-1/log(7)) *
>   ((0,071428571*log(0,071428571))+(0,178571429*log(0,178571429))+(0,178571429*log(0,178571429))+(0,178571429*log(0,178571429))+(0,035714286*log(0,035714286))+(0,178571429*log(0,178571429))+(0,178571429*log(0,178571429)))
>
> countCol5 = (-1/log(7)) *
>   ((0,058823529*log(0,058823529))+(0,235294118*log(0,235294118))+(0,117647059*log(0,117647059))+(0,235294118*log(0,235294118))+(0,117647059*log(0,117647059))+(0,117647059*log(0,117647059))+(0,117647059*log(0,117647059)))
>
> countCol6 = (-1/log(7)) *
>   ((0,208333333*log(0,208333333))+(0,166666667*log(0,166666667))+(0,166666667*log(0,166666667))+(0,083333333*log(0,083333333))+(0,166666667*log(0,166666667))+(0,166666667*log(0,166666667))+(0,041666667*log(0,041666667)))

Comment: Check that `$probabilitas[$i]` contains a float value. I can't find where you define `$probabilitas`

Comment: probabilitas is an array that I have given above

Comment: Ah okay, didn't find the assignment. `log($probabilitas[$i])` -> the parameter will always contain an array, because `$probabilitas` is two-dimensional.

Comment: @digijay im so confuse about what you say hhe

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `$probabilitas[$i]` as a parameter to `log()`, but because of `$probabilitas[$i]` itself contains an array (the second dimension) you get the error message `log() expects parameter 1 to be float, array given`.

Looking at your function I suppose that you are missing the second iterator, so it should be like this:

```
$nEntropy[$j][$i] = 
    ((-1/log(7)) * 
        (($probabilitas[$j][$i]*log($probabilitas[$j][$i])) +
        ...
        ($probabilitas[$j][$i]*log($probabilitas[$j][$i])));
```

I hope this makes it clear. Also your code is missing a bracket, I've added it. Stackoverflow is not a debbugging service though ;-)

Comment: yes this work for cleared error but the results is not like what i want

Comment: If it's not due to a mathematical mistake then it would be a new question.